# How to send an array into function

Tags: arrays, function, go

I'm looking to find syntax that how can I send an array to use in a function as input in Go.

function `UsingArray(a int[])`

Comment: Please read [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func myFunc(arr []int) {
    fmt.Println(arr)
}

func main() {

    var arr = []int{1, 2, 3, 54, 3}
    myFunc(arr)

}
```

Live on [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UtlWyABfBzQ)

P.S. As @torek mentioned, to be precise, you are using a slice not an array. Arrays have constant length and cannot grow, and the function signature for array in my example would be `myFunc(arr [5]int)`.

Comment: Technically, these are *slices* rather than arrays (though non-nil slices have backing or *underlying* arrays).

Answer (score 0):

Sample code in the following ([test it online](https://play.golang.org/p/BfI7X7uqREw)):

```
package main
import "fmt"

func UsingArray(a [6]int) {
    fmt.Println(a)
}

func UsingArray2(a []int) {
    fmt.Println(a)
}

func main() {
    primes := [6]int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
    UsingArray(primes)

    evens := []int{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}
    // will fail since [6]int isn't []int
    // UsingArray(evens)
    UsingArray2(evens)
}
```